# Overlapping Text Matplotlib.text

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to add text descriptions to vertical lines that are present in my plot but the descriptions are overlapping. Here is my attempt to solve the issue:

```
    for date in df['Date'].values:
        ax.axvline(date, c = "black")
        for desc in df['Description'].values:
            for index in df['Date'].index:
                plt.text(df['Date'][index], index, desc)
```

[image]

The placement is not physically overlapping anymore but it seems that the text still is?

Comment: I don't think you've placed enough information in your question to make this an answer, but I expect the problem is that you are adding the description of every line at each vertical line because you have 3 nested for loops. You should probably only have 1 for loop where you extract the value and description for a single date line  plot that vertical line and add the text description.